# Получить путь файла из ListBox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, mediaplayer

Я хочу сделать музыкальный плеер на `listbox`. Проблема в том, что когда нажимаешь на элемент в `lisbox`, он должен начать воспроизводится, но я не знаю как. Посмотрев информацию про `MediaPlayer`, я нашёл воспроизведение по `Uri`, но я не знаю как его получить из `listbox`. Как это реализовать, либо сделать как-то по другому?

Comment: Ну так берите и пишите путь, как пример, в ListBox, а в событии изменения выбора перезапускайте плеер с выбранным путем

Comment: У листбокса есть события изменения выделенного элемента: `SelectedIndexChanged`, `SelectedValueChanged`. Подписывайтесь на какое-либо из них и там получайте значение.

Answer (score 1):

Допустим, у вас есть класс, описывающий музыкальные файлы:

```
class MediaFile
{
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Тогда работа с листбоксом по заполнению его файлами и обработка события изменения выделенного элемента SelectedIndexChanged может выглядеть так:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    MediaPlayer Player;
    List<MediaFile> Files;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Player = new MediaPlayer();
        Files = new List<MediaFile>();
        // заполним список _Files (для краткости просто добавляю два элемента хардкодом)
        Files.Add(new MediaFile() { Order = 1, Name = "Песня 1", Path = @"D:\Media\Music\Память.MP3" });
        Files.Add(new MediaFile() { Order = 2, Name = "Песня 2", Path = @"D:\Media\Music\Пропасть.MP3" });
        // указываем, какое поле класса MediaFile будет являться "значением"
        listBox1.ValueMember = "Order";
        // и какое свойство будет отображаться
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        // указываем датасорс (наш список файлов)
        listBox1.DataSource = _Files;
    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // привязываемся к событию изменения выделенного элемента
        listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // получаем выбранный в листбоксе элемент списка
        MediaFile selectedFile = listBox1.SelectedItem as MediaFile;
        // открываем файл, указанный в свойстве Path выбранного элемента
        Player.Open(new Uri(selectedFile.Path));
        // запускаем проигрывание
        Player.Play();
    }
}
```